# how to read arrayList content using JSTL

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl

I want to read the arrayList objects Attributes that is assigned to request object from JSTL
how can I do this?
i tryed the following

here is the servlet code:

```
ArrayList<Employee> al = new ArrayList<Employee>();
/* code for filling the ArrayList with objects from class Employee */
request.setAttribute("alldata", al);`
```

In my JSP page:

```
<jsp:useBean id="alldata" class="java.util.ArrayList" scope="request">
<c:forEach items="alldata" var="item">
<c:out value="item.getName()"></c:out>
</c:forEach>
</jsp:useBean>
```

but it's not working,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be :

```
<c:forEach items="${alldata}" var="item">
  <c:out value="${item.name}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Note: No `<jsp:useBean>` required.

Comment: I tried it , but I got the following exception "According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute items does not accept any expressions" 
it's my first experience with JSTL :$
thanks skaffman

Comment: @Developer_H: Sounds like you've got a very old version of the JSTL libraries, probably 1.0.  You need 1.1 or higher.

Comment: actually yes , I was using <tlib-version>1.0 I've changed it to <tlib-version>1.1 , but got "javax.servlet.ServletException" :D seems i have incompatibility issue somewhere else (any ideas where it could be? ) .. I'll check it now , thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

use EL expression

```
<c:out value="${item.name}"></c:out>
```